# Use VBA to Open website and click on the video

Tags: vba, excel, video

I'm trying to create a vba code that will open up a website and click on the video on the website. I'm able to open up the website using the code, but don't know what to do to get the code to click play on the video.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
Sub VideoPlayer()

  Dim IE As Object

'Uses exsisting IE page or opens one if one isn't already open
  With CreateObject("Shell.Application").Windows

    If .Count > 0 Then
      ' Get IE
      Set IE = .Item(0) ' or .Item(.Count - 1)
    Else
      ' Create IE
      Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
      IE.Visible = True
    End If

  'web page to navigate to
    IE.Navigate "LINK NAME"

    Set IE = Nothing

  End With

'Waits for the page to load
Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("00:00:03")

'What i need help with...don't know how to play the video
IE.document.???.Clcik

End Sub
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: This has no HTML or an URL so does not qualify as [MCVE]

Answer (score 0):

You haven't supplied much to go on but once you have received the page in full you will have to identify the element to click either through a single identifying trait like `IE.document.getElementById("myVideoId").Click` or cycling through a collection of like elements with `IE.document.getElementsByTagname("div")` looking for an identifying trait that tells you to click that one.

If you do not have a unique identifying trait yet, open the page and use right-click *Inspect Element* to open the elements window and examine the code behind the page.

Finally, when you use `Set IE = Nothing`, you can no longer use the IE object for anything. You will likely want to move that statement to a place *after* the video click.